# Is there a way to select multiple table cells with single javascript click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have basically increased the cursor icon size on the webpage via javascript, and I have a table. Now I would like all overlapping elements in the table with the cursor icon to change their background color (when clicking and dragging). This means changing the area that the mousedown or mouseover is currently able to select and being able to select multiple elements. Is there a way to do this and if so how?

Here is the code for clicking:

```
     $('td').on('mousedown', function (e1) {
    loop();
    flag = 1
    $('td').on('mousemove', function (e2) {
        console.log(document.elementsFromPoint(e2.pageX, e2.pageY))
        if (flag == 1) {
            var tableCell = $(this);
            var setbox = $('.active').attr('id');
            //document.getElementById("tableBack").style.cursor="move";
            switch (setbox) {
                case "lPark":
                    //$(this).text('P');
                    $(this).css('background-color', 'green');
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the code for increasing cursor size:

```
var cursor = document.createElement('canvas'),
ctx = cursor.getContext('2d');

cursor.width = 100;
cursor.height = 100;
var centerX = cursor.width / 2;
var centerY = cursor.height / 2;
var radius = 40 ;

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
ctx.fillStyle = 'green';
ctx.fill();
ctx.lineWidth = 1;
ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
ctx.stroke();
//document.getElementById("tableBack").style.cursor="move";
// set image as cursor (modern browsers can take PNGs as cursor).
document.getElementById("tableBack").style.cursor = 'url(' + cursor.toDataURL() + '), auto';
```

Here is a picture of what I am trying to do

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GWCnd.jpg  (Sorry I don't have enough points to embed)

Notice how cursor is over 4 cells but only 1 of them gets selected, I would like to select all 4.

Comment: Can you provide code snippet? And, what do you mean by overlapping elements?

Comment: Can you show us some code?

Comment: The cursor point is still a single pixel.  The size just helps you see where you're pointing.   You could extrapolate the area of the cursor assuming you know it's size and shape in relation to the single point.

Comment: I added the code, and how can I extrapolate the area and see overlapping table cells (I do know its size and shape (its a circle)).

Comment: what the *&$# is an overlapping table cell.? This question is as clear as mud. Please review [ask]

Comment: I mean the cursor icon is made larger than what the size of a cursor normally is. So When I am over a table the icon could be overlapping 4 different table cells, I would like to change all of their backgrounds at that time. Sorry if it is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

I somehow tried to understand your query. See, there's one thing of course you can do.

There're ample of ways to do this.However, here's a li'l algorithm I'd suggest.

> ```
> 1) capture ctrl key pressed event and save a flag value (suppose boolean) in some hidden field say x;
>   1.1) On Key down save true in x
>   1.2) On Key up save false in x
> 2) now while it is running caputre your mouse click on cell
>   if( x==true)
>       add some highlight class on that cell (which is clicked)
>   else
>       remove some highlight class on that cell
> 3) now for you entire table/grid you have got your highlighted class on items you've selected
> ```

Every phase can be coded as per the requirements. I hope it may give you a bit of idea.

Comment: My code is already doing that, I want to to be able to select multiple table cells which are overlapped by the cursor icon, not just 1 table cell.

Comment: I'm sorry I am not getting your overlapping concept. Would you be more precise. Try to show some screenshot from your table. That may help. Please do depict the overlapping edges.

Comment: Ok I added image in my post, its at this link 

http://imgur.com/a/i3pEp

If you can please help, I've racked my brain trying to figure this out and I am not that great in js, and this project is due soon.

Comment: Don't worry, will try my best to help you out. Stay positive and up Dev. Cheers...

Comment: Okay! So, relating to the image you attached, with that giant green circle you want to color all the related 3 squares (cells) green?

Comment: Yes that's what I would like.